# Dart, try.dart is giving an error using Mixins

Tags: dart

I think the following is correct, but try.dart is giving an error.

```
abstract class Persistence{
    void save(String stuffToSave){
         print('Saved ' + stuffToSave);
    }
}
class Car {
    String model;
    int speed;
    Car(this.model, this.speed);

    void accelerate(int increase){
        this.speed+=increase;
    }
}

class Truck extends Car with Persistence {
    Truck(String model, int speed):super(model, speed);
}

main(){
    Truck myTruck = new Truck('big truck', 0); 
}
```

Here is the error:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect this is a bug. Can you file it at https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues ?